# validate that an html input file field is multiple

Tags: javascript, php

Is there anyway I can validate that an input file field is multiple as in

```
<input type= 'file' name=file[] multiple />
```

either via php or javascript. I already tried google but it seems I couldnt compose the question right.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So u want to say if u can add multiple files in the same input?

Comment: You could check the attribute via jQuery. var attr = $(this).attr('name');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `jQuery` ,

```
if ($('input').attr('multiple')) {
    console.log('Yes, multiple is present');
} else {
    console.log('No, multiple is not present');
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/48zFp/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("Input")[0].hasAttribute("multiple");
```

You can see working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/48zFp/